# Web Server: Theoretical limit to concurrent connections?

Tags: performance, concurrency, webserver

Is there a theoretical limit to how many concurrent connections a single web server can handle?

I've been reading a lot about the [G-WAN](http://gwan.ch/) web server that claims to be the fastest in the world, and the [C10k](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) problem.

**UPDATE**:

Another way to state this question, what is the ranked order of most likely bottlenecks that will prevent additional concurrent connections?

Comment: I don't trust G-WAN because their HTML text is not selectable. Clearly if they can't make a sensible website then they can't make a sensible web server

Comment: What does a web server have to do with "concurrent users"?  Do you mean concurrent *connections*?

Comment: @KirkWoll, Yes I meant "connections" and have updated the original post.

Comment: Whoever is suggesting this be closed, I disagree with your reasoning.  It seems on-topic, given that any developer attempting to write software that scales could potentially ask the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck can be:

1. the user-mode application (that's why a server is faster than another)
2. the network (wave this bottleneck with localhost tests or a 40 GbE LAN)
3. the kernel (patch the kernel, write your drivers, or use another OS)

So the game is to resolve those problems in their order of being most likely to happen.

Disclamer: I am involved in the development of the G-WAN project but I have nothing to do with the question above.

Answer (score -2):

Theoretical limit?  No.  It's a function of available processing power, RAM, latency, sockets, bandwidth and any number of other factors, but there is no *theoretical* upper bound to be placed on this, except perhaps something involving the total amount of matter and energy in the universe.

EDIT: To those voting this ancient answer down, keep in mind that it was written in response to the question in the form it was asked originally (it consisted of only the first line of the question, the elaboration was added much later).  I'm leaving it here because I stand by the contention.  If you feel like down-voting this answer, I'd much appreciate it if you left a comment identifying some theoretical upper-bound that I've missed.  There could be a novel theorem lurking here if you can identify a theoretical limit!

Comment: Which should also be related to the total amount of matter and energy in the universe, according to a rather famous law :p

Comment: I think there is room here to explore what the theoretical limits are on various OS platforms, but probably not a topic for SO.

Comment: Then why is it that even the best web servers like NGINX seem to make out at around 10k connections when it's obviously not bandwidth, memory or CPU since all are waaaaaaay under utilized in benchmark tests.

Comment: Because they are hitting some other limit.  It might be that the granularity of the memory operations cause giant cache miss ratios or pipeline stalls.  It might be that the OS is not designed to provision and retire sockets that fast.  This is not a "theoretical" limit though - it's entirely a product of the particular implementation on a particular OS on a particular machine, configured a particular way.